# SteamKit2 How to use new callbacks?

Tags: c#, steambot

How can I make ConnectedCallback for `OnConnected` method using SteamKit2?
Code (Access Error):

```
new Callback<SteamClient.ConnectedCallback>(OnConnected, manager);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I really dont understand your approach of doing this.
How I did it is this

```
_manager = new CallbackManager(_steamClient);
_manager.Subscribe<SteamClient.ConnectedCallback>(OnConnected);
_manager.Subscribe<SteamClient.DisconnectedCallback>(OnDisconnected);
_manager.Subscribe<SteamUser.LoggedOnCallback>(OnLoggedOn);
_manager.Subscribe<SteamUser.LoggedOffCallback>(OnLoggedOff);
_manager.Subscribe<SteamUser.AccountInfoCallback>(OnAccountInfo);
_manager.Subscribe<SteamUser.UpdateMachineAuthCallback>(OnMachineAuth);
_manager.Subscribe<SteamFriends.FriendMsgCallback>(OnChatMessage);
_manager.Subscribe<SteamFriends.FriendsListCallback>(OnFriendList)
```

where of course `_manager` is `private static CallbackManager _manager;`

You can see all of my code at https://github.com/rishav394/Steam-bot but be warned, I could be using an older version of the steamkit2 and this was made for learning purposes and so the code is not very well organised.